# Changing the anchor size for transfer learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I want to detect some small objects and I wonder if changing anchor size in Faster_rcnn.config file will make the model perform better in transfer learning or the model will require to be trained from scratch?
I am using pre-trained models on the Object detection model zoo as the fine-tuning checkpoint.

The ".config" file has the following parameters:

```
first_stage_anchor_generator {
grid_anchor_generator {
scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
height_stride: 8
width_stride: 8
```

Thanks for your answers and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way around is by using Kmeans for clustering. This is a very useful document.
[Kmeans](https://medium.com/@medhijoydeep/anchor-boxes-in-faster-rcnn-6bd566ec4935)